# how to integrate two java classes and use it in android?

Tags: android

I am developing android application but i don't know how to integrate two activity files(two java classes) with one-onether like we are doing in java?If u have solution please tell me how to do it? 
-Thanks in advance.

Comment: kateshiya: Do you want to transfer the control from one activity to another, similar to subroutine call, am i right??

Comment: You should follow Google's Android tutorials, they address this very base level type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how to [share data between Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3).

Also look at how an Activity [starts another Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen).

Comment: @azad: "thanks for your help.The information is very useful to me." is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)" [that is the most helpful to you]

Answer (score 2):

for moving one avtivity to another use:
startActivity(new Intent(yourcurrentclass.this, secondclass.class));

And specify the second Activity in AndroidMenifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preferences or achieve it by passing data via intent